# How to increase Button hit test tap size via interaction contentShape?

Tags: ios, button, swiftui

I want to increase the tap target for my Button without affecting the layout. The button size should remain the same (50pt) but should allow tapping outside of it (another 50pt) to trigger the button. I understand the [contentShape](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contentshape(_:_:eofill:)) API should be able to do this using the `interaction` kind, however I can’t get it working when applied to the Button nor its label. You have to tap directly in the label’s frame, can’t tap on the Text underneath nor above it. What’s the right way to do this?

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    Button {
        print("Tapped")
    } label: {
        Text("A")
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .background(Color.accentColor.opacity(0.2))
            .clipShape(.circle)
            .contentShape(.interaction, .rect(cornerRadius: 0).inset(by: -50))
    }
    .contentShape(.interaction, .rect(cornerRadius: 0).inset(by: -50))
        
    Text("Test")
}
```

Comment: If you are using a plain button, simply putting `.padding(25)` will add 50 pts total to the tap area of the button. A button's tap area is the same size as its label. If you want to us a fancier button, I would consider appropriate padding inside of a custom `ButtonStyle`.